# VBA copyfile it it doesn't exist

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of file in 2 columns `A` and `B`.

- `A` column is the source the B
- `B` column is the destination

The code below copy file from source to destination. But if the destination exists it give me errors. What is the condition so that if it find that it exists it will not do anyting ??

What is the wrong with the code ?

```
  Sub FC_Copy()

Dim ClientsFolderDestination
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim rep_destination
Dim source

    lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("XClients").Cells(Application.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 5 To lastrow
        source = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("XClients").Cells(i, 1).Value
        ClientsFolderDestination= ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("XClients").Cells(i, 2).Value
        If fso.FileExists(source) Then
            rep_destination = Left(ClientsFolderDestination, Len(ClientsFolderDestination) - Len(fso.GetFileName(ClientsFolderDestination)) - 1)

         If Not fso.FolderExists(rep_destination) Then
          sub_rep = Split(rep_destination, "\")
          myrep = sub_rep(0)
          If Not fso.FolderExists(myrep) Then
              MkDir myrep
           End If
           For irep = 1 To UBound(sub_rep)
              myrep = myrep & "\" & sub_rep(irep)
               If Not fso.FolderExists(myrep) Then
                    MkDir myrep
               End If
         Next
    End If

            fso.CopyFile source, ClientsFolderDestination
        End If
    Next i
end sub
```

Comment: What is `iRow`? What is `destination`?

Comment: @SiddharthRout i edit the code

Comment: One last question, what is the value that you have in col A and Col B? Type it here. There is an easier way to do this

Comment: c:\Mycomputer\Folder\client1.xlsx  and the destination is : c:\Mycomputer\folder2\client1.xlsx

Comment: I have posted an answer. See if that helps you. You may have to refresh the page

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

1. This doesn't use `Microsoft Scripting Runtime Library`.
2. It uses one common function to check for existence of file and folder
3. It caters for destination paths like `C:\Sample.xlsx`

**Code**

```
Sub FC_Copy()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim source As String, Destination As String, sTemp As String
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim MyAr As Variant

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("XClients")

    With ws
        '~~> Find Last Row
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 5 To lRow            
            source = .Range("A" & i).Value
            Destination = .Range("B" & i).Value                
            MyAr = Split(Destination, "\")

            '~~> This check is required for destination paths like C:\Sample.xlsx
            If UBound(MyAr) > 1 Then
                sTemp = MyAr(0)                
                For j = 1 To UBound(MyAr)
                    sTemp = sTemp & "\" & MyAr(j)
                    If Not FileFolderExists(sTemp) = True Then MkDir sTemp
                Next j
            End If

            If Not FileFolderExists(Destination) Then FileCopy source, Destination
        Next i
    End With
End Sub

Public Function FileFolderExists(strFullPath As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo Whoa
    If Not Dir(strFullPath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then FileFolderExists = True
    On Error GoTo 0
Whoa:
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

```
If Not fso.FileExists(ClientsFolderDestination) Then
    fso.CopyFile source, ClientsFolderDestination
End If
```

or if you want to **overwrite** the destination file

```
fso.CopyFile source, ClientsFolderDestination, True
```

[CopyFile Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1wf9e7w)